# PostgreSQL: update table ensuring rows have unique timestamp (no duplicate unix timestamp)

Tags: sql, postgresql, crud

I am having a table of GPS traces with Unix timestamp as shown below:

```
 SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10;
    id     |    lat     |    lon     |  seconds   | speed 
-----------+------------+------------+------------+-------
 536889001 | 41.1794675 | -8.6017187 | 1460465697 |  1.25
 536889001 | 41.1794709 |  -8.601675 | 1460465698 |     2
 536889001 | 41.1794636 | -8.6016337 | 1460465700 |  1.25
 536889001 | 41.1794468 | -8.6016014 | 1460465700 |   2.5
 536889001 | 41.1794114 | -8.6015662 | 1460465701 |   3.5
 536889001 | 41.1794376 | -8.6015672 | 1460465703 |   1.5
 536889001 |   41.17944 | -8.6015516 | 1460465703 |   1.5
 536889001 | 41.1794315 | -8.6015353 | 1460465704 |   1.5
 536889001 | 41.1794367 | -8.6015156 | 1460465705 |  1.25
 536889001 | 41.1794337 | -8.6014974 | 1460465706 |  1.75
 (10 rows)
```

Column `seconds` is the Unix timestamp. I would like to update the table by selecting ONLY one row, for rows with timestamps logged more than 1. So for example in above, we see two rows each at timestamp `1460465700` and `1460465703`.

Comment: You are not clear with your question: a) Do you want to delete rows from your table so only one row with unique timestamps is left, or b) Do you want a SELECT query which will return you a list of rows with unique timestamps? What is purpose of 'id' column as it keeps same value?

Comment: Since `mytable` was created as `select from some tables....` I will post a new question so clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

Without a unique id on the row, this is tricky.  But assuming that the *combination* of values is unique, you can use:

```
update gps
    set . . . 
    from (select gps.*, count(*) over (partition by id, seconds) as cnt,
                 row_number() over (partition by id, seconds order by seconds) as seqnum
          from gps
         ) gps2
     where gps2.cnt > 1 and pgs2.seqnum = 1 and
           gps2.seconds = pgs.seconds and
           gps2.id = gps.id and
           gps2.speed = gps.speed and
           gps2.lat = gps.lat and
           gps2.lon = gps.lon ;
```

I would advise you to add a unique id to the table, so this is much simpler (and guaranteed to work even if the table has duplicates).